# RTC DS3231 always remember the old time

Tags: esp8266, esp32, rtc, ds3231-alarms

I try to change time on windows to test my programing condition but RTC usually keep old time when i change time on windows and re-upload the code . I'm also removing the battery  and cut the power it is still not working.

here is my set up and library is https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib

```
void setup () {
 
#ifndef ESP8266
  while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
#endif
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("ESP start...");
  pinMode(Ledpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  
  
  delay(3000); // wait for console opening

if (! rtc.begin()) {
  Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
 while (1);
}

 
  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, lets set the time!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date &amp; time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date &amp; time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
    // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
  }
   
}
```

Comment: Does it print “RTC lost power, lets set the time!”?

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't seen the `rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__),F(__TIME__)));` construction, which uses the `DateTime(char*,char*)` routine from  https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/4ece412b89ed3b72093174d19b50afcf8ed6c6a8/src/RTClib.cpp#L281 and the C environment variables `__DATE__, __TIME__`  -- Rather than re-upload the code, you might need to re-compile to code to update the time encoded in the binary file.